# JavaFX: how to connect the main application object to the FXML controller

Tags: javafx, controller, fxml

An FXML newbie question. I have a JavaFX Application class which does not do a whole lot (anymore) other than setting up the scene, and a controller class which gets instantiated when the FXML file is loaded and where I moved much of the logic (because seemingly the main class and the controller class are not really aware of one another).

However, I have a method which sets up setOnDragDropped on the scene. Normally, my main app would handle drag events, but because of FXML, that logic needs to be in the controller now (for File->Open for example). I have not found a way to setup DragDrop from the controller because the "scene" is only known in the main class. And since I don't instantiate the controller directly (indirectly instantiated when FXML file is loaded), I can't pass it object references easily.

How can I link the main and controller so I can have a bit more flexibility in where I put the logic? Or how can I migrate the scene dragDrop handler to the controller?
Thanks

Comment: To migrate the drag handler to the controller, register a listener with some node's `sceneProperty`. When the `scene` changes to something non-null, set up the drag and drop handlers on it. Everything else in your question just seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml/14190310#14190310

Comment: that did the trick, thanks. I have this sexy lambda expression in the controller's initialize method:
`gridPane.sceneProperty().addListener((observable, oldvalue, newvalue) -> {

            if (newvalue!=null) setupDragNDrop(gridPane.getScene());
        });`